# Calculate Grand Total from my total of Each Group in my SSRS Report

Tags: ssrs-2008

[image]

I want Grand Total of Each Group total as shown in image, but i dont want to repeat my grand total so i have placed it outside of my Group1. How to calculate Grand Total outside of my Group1.

My Report Structure is as Below -

[image]

[image]

In Quantity Field which is showing -86 , expression i wrote is as follows -
    =Last(SUM(Fields!BalanceQty.Value,"Group1"))

In the image - result of Quantity is **-86** , but my required Output is **41** i.e. 26 + 16 + 30 -31 .

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please don't include such illegible images in your question.  Rather, include text, preferably sample table data and expected output.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen. Unless the question has been updated since, there is nothing wrong with the images. They are perfectly clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I understand correctly, you want to sum the values shown in the cell directly above the grand total cell (in your design).

If that's the case then get the textbox name from the 'cell' you want to sum and then do

```
=SUM(ReportItems!myTextBoxName.Value)
```

Answer (score 0):

dont you have on grouping "add totals after" or "add totals before" option. This will show you a grand total; plus and sub-totals for each category.